# Surveymonkey Custom Variable for browser User Agent?

Tags: surveymonkey

How do I set up a link from a website to a survey which carries across the Respondent's user agent string from their browser as a SM Custom Variable ?  I want to track how many respond from a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can just do it with JavaScript. First make sure you have the custom variable created on the survey. Then you can do something like:

```
link = document.getElementById("smlink"); // Or whatever ID you have for the link
href = link.getAttribute("href");
href += "user_agent=" + window.navigator.userAgent; // Or however you're getting the user agent
link.setAttribute("href", href);
```

Or set the href on the link to `javascript:void(0)` and have a click event listener that does `window.location = weblink + "user_agent=" + window.navigator.userAgent`.

That was just an example in plain JavaScript there's likely better ways to do this depending on the framework you're using.

Comment: Thank you General Kandalaft I'll pass that on to the webdev.